# IBM Watson Assistant: How to ask a series of questions and store related answers?

Tags: ibm-cloud, chatbot, ibm-watson, watson-assistant

I want to ask a series of question , taking each input and saving them in a context variable and then moving to the next question.
The problem is whenever a user responds IBM Watson starts classifying it into intents. and goes to that specific intent. What i want would look something like this:

- Whats your name?
- user input = xyz
- xyz gets stored in username and then the bot asks the next question
- whats your organ name

and so on.

Comment: Have you looked into using slots? That allows to react depending on the answer and directly store the results.

Comment: i have but for that we have to check on intents or something and name/organisation name isn't something we want classification for

Comment: The name and organisation would be entities. And you can always access the full input: https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/assistant?topic=assistant-expression-language#expression-language-builtin-vars

Answer (score 0):

My advice would be to work with slots and to define entities for what you want to capture. This allows for a more natural flow. "Henrik from xyz" could be directly stored as name "Henrik" and "yyz" as org.

If you just want to have a series of questions and store whatever was answered, take a look at [special conditions](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/assistant?topic=assistant-dialog-overview#dialog-overview-conditions). If you use **true** as condition and store the [entire input](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/assistant?topic=assistant-expression-language#expression-language-builtin-vars) into a context variable, you get what you asked for.